# Best approch to migrate SharePoint Site from 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, migration

Best approch to migrate SharePoint Site from 2010 to 2013.I want to migrate site develop in SharePoint 2010 to 2013. What is best approach ?

Comment: We just finished our migration from 2007/2010 to 2013 and just as a tip: check with your users if they REALLY need the data that you are about to migrate. We made that mistake and basically spend a lot of time migrating content/sites that in the end were more or less useless ;)

Answer (score 4):

To upgrade from SharePoint 2010 Products to SharePoint 2013, you use the database-attach method to upgrade. In the database-attach method, you first create and configure a SharePoint 2013 farm. Then you copy the content and service application databases from the SharePoint 2010 Products farm, and then attach and upgrade the databases. This upgrades the data to the new version. Site owners can then upgrade individual site collections.

For detailed steps:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483(v=office.15).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp142375.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2012/07/17/upgrading-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step.aspx

There are also third Party tools:

https://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools

http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx

http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-to-sharepoint-migration-docave/

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/step-by-step-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-database-to-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an approach which increase chances of successful migration.

**Test Migration:**To understand your environment before you upgrade it, and to plan for the time that an upgrade will require, you should try one or more trial upgrades. The goal of testing upgrade is to find and fix issues and develop confidence in the outcome before the real upgrade.

**Couple of points to be noted:**

- Know what is in your environment. Do a full survey first.
- Make your test environment as similar as possible to your real
  environment.
- Use real data.
- Run multiple tests.
- Do not ignore errors or warnings.
- Test the upgraded environment, not just the upgrade process.

**Final Migration:** After complete testing, you have to perform the final migration.

- Ensure that the environment is fully functioning before you begin to
  upgrade
- Perform a trial upgrade on a test farm first.
- Plan for capacity.
- Clean up before you upgrade
- Back up your databases.
- Optimize your environment before upgrade.
- (Optional) Set the original databases to read-only if you want to
  keep your original environment available while you upgrade.
- After upgrade, review the Upgrade Status page and upgrade logs to
  determine whether you must address issues. Then review the upgraded
  sites.
- Defer upgrade for site collections until you can get updated
  customizations to support 2013 mode.

Source: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261992(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261992%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

I highlight the approaches, Anachal already mentioned how to migrate the 2010 to 2013 using the DB restore method. I always prefer DB upgrade unless you have 3rd party tool.